# Mapbox GL draw typescript definition

Tags: mapbox-gl, mapbox-gl-js

Is there a typed definition available for the mapbox-gl-draw? It seems I cannot find one in the dt.

Answer (score 0):

`mapbox-gl-draw` does not currently its types. I'd be open to a PR that instruments the code with Flow to make this possible.